# Lambda boto3 background functions with api

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm trying to build a basic AWS Lambda API and function setup to do the following:

- **Part 1:** Client calls function with api and runs both a background 1 min function to process data and a quick messesge to client in browser.
- **Part 2:** When background function is complete it returns 302 redirect to the client with a generated link.

I'm stuck on Part 2. How can I go from the background function to the API back to the client?

I'm using python boto3 for my Lambda scripts.

Answer (score 2):

This is AWS Lambda so your client doesn't have a persistent connection to the server-side code.

Here is an idea of one way to build this:

- your client makes an API request that triggers a Lambda function
- on invocation, your Lambda function generates a new, unique id (a UUID), writes that to DynamoDB so that this UUID can later be associated with the result of the background processing
- the Lambda kicks off the background processing, passing the UUID to it
- the Lambda returns the generated UUID to the client
- the background processing happens asynchronously, ultimately writing any results to the DynamoDB item associated with the UUID that triggered it
- the client polls another API periodically, say every 10s, sending in the UUID it was given
- the polled Lambda takes the presented UUID, does a lookup in DynamoDB and returns a 302 redirect to a URL result, or an indication that the results aren't ready yet (e.g. HTTP 404)
- some process that you create removes the item from DynamoDB later (or not)

Comment: Really helpful overview ofthe workflow. Given me some direction thanks so much, 